# ImportError: cannot import name 'Bio' from partially initialized module 'bios.models' (most likely due to a circular import )

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

First app models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from projects.models import Project

class Bio(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
 project = models.ManyToManyField(Project,blank=True)
 number = models.CharField(max_length=11,default=None,null=True)
 text = models.TextField(max_length=280)

 def __str__(self):
   return self.name
```

2nd app model.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from bios.models import Bio
from django.conf import settings
 
class Project(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
   bio = models.ManyToManyField(Bio)
   desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

I am getting a circular import error.
How to resolve this ????

My Aim  is to create a project that has  many to many relations with  bio and I want bio to show project

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you'll need to rethink how you're setting up your models.  ```Project``` depends on ```Bio``` and ```Bio``` depends on ```Project```.  Thus your circular import issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the models directly from `ManyToManyField` and you don't have to import. :

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Here, removed importing Bio 
from django.conf import settings
 
class Project(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
   bio = models.ManyToManyField('bios.Bio') # Here
   desc = models.TextField(max_length=200)

   def __str__(self):
     return self.name
```

Comment: ok thanks, But I have some other query like then  if I select bio in project form then      
 will it be automatically be shown in the bio detail page ???

Comment: Yes absolutely, there is no other difference than using the previous method. It is pointing toward `Bio` of `bios`. So, it will be shown perfectly.